# A new table in R based on fields and data from existing one

Tags: r

I need to raise the question again as it was closed as duplicated, but the issue hasn't been resolved.

So, I'm working on international trade data and have the following table at the moment with 5 different values for commodity_code (commod_codes = c('85','84','87','73','29')):

```
year trade_flow reporter partner commodity_code                 commodity trade_value_usd
1 2012     Import  Belarus   China             29         Organic chemicals       150863100
2 2013     Import  Belarus   China             29         Organic chemicals       151614000
3 2014     Import  Belarus   China             29         Organic chemicals        73110200
4 2015     Import  Belarus   China             29         Organic chemicals       140396300
5 2016     Import  Belarus   China             29         Organic chemicals       135311600
6 2012     Import  Belarus   China             73 Articles of iron or steel       100484600
```

I need to create a new table that looks simple (commodity codes in top row, years in first column and corresponding trade values in cells):

```
year             commodity_code     
             29   73  84  85  87
1998        value1      ...   value 5                           
1999                                
…                       
2016
```

* I used reshape() but didn't succeed.

Would appreciate your support.

Comment: You should look for `spread` function from `tidyr` package.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Gangesh Dubey, thank you for this help. This piece of code is even better for me since I'm trying to extensively use the tidyvesre() package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are duplicate permutations, I would suggest to use this code (though not in base R - uses dplyr and tidyr packages)

```
as.data.frame(trade_data[,c("year","commodity_code","trade_value_usd")] %>% group_by (year,commodity_code)%>% summarise( sum(trade_value_usd))%>%spread(commodity_code,3))
```

Comment: Please note that there is a discrepancy in your description of the solution you want ("commodity codes as first column, years as top row and corresponding trade values in cells") and the sample format you have suggested. The code should produce output for the sample report format.

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood you correctly, here is a one-liner in base R.

```
xtabs(trade_value_usd ~ year + commodity_code, data = df);
#year          29        73
#  2012 150863100 100484600
#  2013 151614000         0
#  2014  73110200         0
#  2015 140396300         0
#  2016 135311600         0
```

Explanation: Use `xtabs` to cross-tabulate `trade_value_usd` as a function of `year` (rows) and `commodity_code` (columns).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "year trade_flow reporter partner commodity_code                 commodity trade_value_usd
1 2012     Import  Belarus   China             29         'Organic chemicals'       150863100
2 2013     Import  Belarus   China             29         'Organic chemicals'       151614000
3 2014     Import  Belarus   China             29         'Organic chemicals'        73110200
4 2015     Import  Belarus   China             29         'Organic chemicals'       140396300
5 2016     Import  Belarus   China             29         'Organic chemicals'       135311600
6 2012     Import  Belarus   China             73 'Articles of iron or steel'       100484600
", header = T, row.names = 1)
```